# Insert result of select into temp table in the procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In procedure, I need to make two or more queries resulting the same columns and unite that resulting rows in one returning table. Example

```
CREATE PROC tmpProc
AS
BEGIN

  -- Making first query
  SELECT * INTO #resultTable FROM tableOne;

  -- Making second query, resulting columns are totally the same
  SELECT * INTO #resultTable FROM tableTwo;

  -- Return rowset from temporary table
  SELECT * From #resultTable;

END
```

But this type of proc failed, because `There is already an object named #resultTable in the database`

Comment: just change the second select to 'insert into #resultTable  SELECT * FROM tableTwo`

Comment: Why on earth would you even use a temporary table for this? A simple union statement with no inserts works.

Comment: @ZLK, UNION has some magic in the merging mismatching columns, or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "mismatching"? Data types? If they can all be cast to the same type, it shouldn't matter (e.g. varchar '1', '2', '3' can be unioned with int 4, 5, 6). If you mean column names, that's not an issue either. If you mean the columns are out of order, then you need to specify the column names in the selects.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if columns are same in two tables.

```
CREATE PROC tmpProc
AS
BEGIN

  -- Making first query
  SELECT *  FROM tableOne;

  UNION ALL
  SELECT *  FROM tableTwo;

END
```

Comment: This is wrong. The answer is *either* UNION ALL or SELECT INTO followed by INSERT. The UNION will eliminate the need for a temp table at all. A mix of the two is simply an invalid solution.

Comment: Except you no longer can return the result from a temp table that you never created. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite It's my miss.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROC tmpProc
AS
BEGIN

  -- Making first query
  SELECT * INTO #resultTable FROM tableOne;

  -- Making second query, resulting columns are totally the same
    INSERT INTO #resultTable SELECT * FROM tableTwo;

  -- Return rowset from temporary table
  SELECT * From #resultTable;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two sample to do that:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#resultTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #resultTable
    ------   1  use insert into select---------------------
    SELECT * INTO #resultTable FROM tableOne;
    INSERT INTO  #resultTable  SELECT * FROM tableTwo
    ------   1  use union ---------------------
    SELECT * INTO #resultTable FROM (
        SELECT * FROM  tableOne 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM tableTwo
   ) AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE PROC tmpProc
AS
BEGIN

  select * into #resultTable from (

  SELECT col1,col2,col3...coln FROM tableOne;

  union all

  SELECT col1,col2,col3...coln FROM tableTwo;
  ) as a

  SELECT * From #resultTable;

 END
```